# How could I get duration of my VM halt?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

my VM just halted a long time, and I want to check the halt beginning date. There are so many properties about Virtual_Guest and I didn't find the power state information such as 'halted'. I tried `getNetworkMonitorIncidents`,

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/

Does SL support to show power state beginning date or duration?

Answer (score 0):

To know the halt beginning date for the vm, you can use the following rest api: just you have to change the label data in this rest api for your "fullyQualifiedDomainName" in the position “set me”.

1. Method: GET

   ```
    https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Event_Log/getAllObjects?objectFilter={"label":{"operation":"*= set me"},"eventName":{"operation":"Power Off"}}
   ```

To get your "fullyQualifiedDomainName" use this rest api:

2. Method: GET

   ```
   https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtualGuestId]/getObject
   ```

Also to get the power state of the vm, you can use this rest api:

3. Method: GET

   ```
   https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtualGuestId]/getPowerState
   ```

SL supports the beginning date of the vm, but does not support the duration of this. You can calculate the duration according to the events shown by the first rest api, that is above.

Comment: Appreciated it~